# Python 3.5 modify xml without changing the declaration

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I'm trying to modify an existing XML file using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` library.

I've managed to modify my XML as needed, however, when using the `write(path, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)`...

...the declaration is written with single quotes instead of double quotes like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

which is critical for me.

Is there a way I can keep the declaration as is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: xml.etree.elementtree.ElemenTtree.write() declaration tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471378/python-xml-etree-elementtree-elementtree-write-declaration-tag)

Comment: write() method for xml.etree.ElementTree has hardcoded with single quotes as in previous python versions, so the following SO question might help to address your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471378/python-xml-etree-elementtree-elementtree-write-declaration-tag

Comment: I don't see there the actual solution of the OP. He just explained what should be done. As I'm a complete beginner, I'd like someone to help me through this with code example